# GTK3 applications are ugly in XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, gtk

I am running Arch Linux with XFCE. GTK2 apps, like Thunar, look nice:

[image: looks good!]

On the other hand, GTK3 apps, like Rhythmbox, look pretty messed up.

[image: ick]

I get the same results with both the XFCE theme and the naos theme (with the gtk3 port). Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe your themes just are incompatible with GTK 3.6? I've heard complaints about GTK 3 breaking theme compatibility between minor releases.

Comment: Seems likely. I know Gnome Shell 3.6 caused some ugly stuff to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the theme was not properly loaded for GTK+3 applications: a [bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9272) in `xfce4-settings` prevented it. Running an application from the shell (e.g. launching `gtk3-demo`) should exhibit the problem.

There are a fistful of [workarounds](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK+#GTK.2B_3.x) that can be attempted: if you updated `xfce4-settings` to at least 4.10.1 **and** changed the theme after that update the problem should have been resolved by itself.